# Why does `select distinct` make my psycopg2 transaction with Redshift not read only?

Tags: amazon-redshift, psycopg2

## Background

I'm creating a connection to a Redshift database from python using `psycopg2` as follows:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(my_credentials)
conn.set_session(
    readonly=True
)
```

I then use `conn` to create (unnamed, i.e. "client side") cursors (`conn.cursor()`) and use them to fetch results.

I have a particular query which tries to fetch a result set similar to the following:

```sql
    with 

    _cte_1 as (
        select distinct,
            some_identifier,
            some_metadata
        from
            my_schema.my_table
    ),

    _cte_2 as (
        select
            some_identifier,
            some_different_metadata
        from
            my_schema.my_other_table
    )

    select * from _cte_1 left join _cte_2 using (some_identifier)
```

The above fails with `ReadOnlySqlTransaction: transaction is read-only` *unless* the `distinct` in `_cte_1` is removed, in which case the result set can be fetched normally.

*Please note that I am unable to provide a minimal reproducible example as I don't know which facets of the database I'm interacting with I need to replicate to reproduce this behaviour; in fact this is kind of the question!*

## Question

What about the `distinct` here makes the transaction *not* read only?

If it helps (unsure if relevant), both `my_schema.my_table` and `my_schema.my_other_table` are models in a `dbt` pipeline.

My `psycopg2` version is `2.9.9 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)`.

Comment: I cannot replicate using community version of Postgres, so this must be a Redshift thing. I'm going to guess that from here [Redshift Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SELECT_list.html): *DISTINCT  Option that eliminates duplicate rows from the result set, based on matching values in one or more columns.* means Redshift is doing this as a delete?

Comment: Thanks for this @AdrianKlaver. Yes, distinct doing a delete from a temporary table or something under the hood sounds quite plausible. I will see if I can test this theory somehow when I have time to do so.